# How to make Stream Of Objects from a Dynamic Source in Java?

Tags: java, java-stream

I am trying to solve a problem, looks like its not possible with Java.

I have some code that calls a processObject(SomeObject someObject) and the method process it. I am trying to encapsulate this whole thing and want to get a stream of someObjects.

Below is my sample program:

```
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class ProcessObject {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 0;
        ProcessObject processObject = new ProcessObject();
        while (true) {
            processObject.processObject(new SomeObject("Hello " + i++));
        }
    }

    public void processObject(SomeObject someObject) {
        System.out.println(someObject);

    }
    //TODO
    public Stream<SomeObject> getStream(){
        //Producer here should wait and produce Objects as soon as 
        //they become available like "processObject" method.
        return Stream.generate(() -> new SomeObject("Hello "));
    }
}


class SomeObject {
    public String name;

    public SomeObject(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

The static main method keeps on generating SomeObjects and call method processObject to process them and it prints them. So, all is good.

I want to create a stream of SomeObject so that instead of calling the method to process them, I will just use streams to process them, something like this:

> public Stream getStream();

Now with Java 8 or Java 9, there are Streams available. But put the condition of IMMUTABLE characteristics from the sources they are being generated.

**How to create a stream and then add elements to stream as soon as they become available like a true pipeline?**

I thought to use a BlockingQueue and use it in Stream Generate method as Producer like blockingQueue.take() but it never compiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a `BlockingQueue` to feed the `Stream` you will need the producer and the consumer running on different threads.

Here I am using my main thread to consume the stream and a new thread to feed it through a `BlockingQueue` to demonstrate.

```
public void test(String[] args) {
    // My queue
    BlockingQueue<BigInteger> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(10);

    // A Stream of it's contents.
    Stream<BigInteger> biStream = Stream.generate(() -> {
        try {
            return queue.take();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    });

    // Feed the queue from a thread.
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        // Must be final to be accessible inside `run`.
        final AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger();

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Slow feed to the queue.
            while (true) {
                // Add a new number to the queue.
                queue.add(BigInteger.valueOf(i.getAndIncrement()));
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();

    // DEMO - Consumes the queue printing contents as they arrive.
    biStream.filter(x -> x.testBit(2))
            .limit(20)
            .forEach(x -> System.out.println(x));
}
```

Comment: true that BlockingQueue needs at least two threads.....i will try it tonight at home...thanks :)
I think I got what I need.

Comment: What’s the point of waking up every second just to call `queue.poll(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` again when there is no new element? Why not simply calling `take()` in the first place?

Comment: @Holger - Good point. Fixed! I was trying to deal with the `InterruptedException` quietly.

Comment: @abcdef12 there's no way to do what you want without two threads regardless the implementation. How would the current thread make data available if it is waiting for the data to arrive?

Comment: @daniu I took different approach to solve it. I am not using streams at all. I am now using Blocking Queue, Semaphore. I made a pool in which Semaphore controls the producer and consumer and allocate threads on load demand to consumer/producer. Like a balancer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you can't mutate a local variable `i` in the lambda expression, isn't it? Well, since a lambda is basically an anonymous inner class, you can just put `i` as a field of the inner class!

```
Stream<String> stream = Stream.generate(new Supplier<String>() {
    int i = 0;
    // if you have any other state you want to mutate, put it here as well!
    @Override
    public String get() {
        return "Hello" + i++;
    }
});
// prints Hello0 to Hello9!
System.out.println(stream.limit(10).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```